# What is real difference between Observable and Mediator patterns in JS?

Tags: javascript, observable, mediator

Can someone tell me a real difference of them in JS programming? Because for now I understand them just something equal to each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the Mediator and the Observer patterns is that the observer distributes the exchange of information between objects, and the mediator, on the contrary, encapsulates the interaction between other objects.

By the way, they are really very similar with have two main environments: `subscribe` and `publish` in overall. That's the common point of juniors misunderstanding in them.